# How can I add a mouse over listener to a IKImageBrowserCell?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can I add a "mouse over" listener to a IKImageBrowserCell (which is not a NSView or a NSCell), but simply inheriting from a NSObject ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `IKImageBrowserCell` is a subclass of NSObject,  I suggest you to use the mouse event methods in your `IKImageBrowserView` subclass.  You can detect the cell under the mouse using the respective event's locationInWindow  as below

```
- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
     NSPoint point = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
     NSInteger itemIndex = [self indexOfItemAtPoint:point];
     //Use this itemIndex to do manipulations on your item or cell.
}
```

It will be in `NSResponder` class.  `IKmageBrowserView` is subclass of `NSView` which is a subclass for `NSResponder`.

`IKImageBrowserView : NSView : NSResponder : NSObject`

Comment: I can't find the method you mention (mouseEntered) in the IKImageBrowserView. Could you give me more information about it ? thanks

Comment: hey thanks. I've tried and it works a bit weird: it is not always triggered, I don't understand when it is triggered, it seems a bit random. I would have expected it to be trigger continuously, every time the mouse move to a new pixel inside the view.

Comment: try out other mouse events too.. like mouseMoved: mouseExited: etc